# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can not access internet

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my internet is not working on this at all.

I've the network cable plugged in but it doesn't seem to be working.

Could anyone please help me on this ?

Just so everyone knows, I do have the Gigabyte Motherboard. (This might help you to understand the issue faster)

Thanks!
-Sanju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Network.

**You don't see a wired interface**

If you don't see a *wired* interface there, your adapter is not being recognized by Ubuntu, probably because it is too new or too old. You should identify the exact model of your motherboard and check

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

for compatibility support.

If you don't find your card there, you know what the problem is and might want to research a bit in order to be able to use it with Ubuntu.

If you find your card there, post the exact model here.

**You see a wired interface**

If you see a wired interface, your adapter is being recognized and you might want to check its configuration in order to match your network settings by clicking in the "Options" button on the bottom of the screen.

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for the help on this. I got this working. I needed to make some changes in BIOS settings. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you sorted this out. Cheers